# How can i send message to different ip's through microsoft message queue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, message-queue

I am working on intranet based application ( visitor management system of my university), messages are sending and recieving through message queue , i want to send message to particular department which i selected in dropdown menu like chemistry department can only view its visitors or IT department can only view its visitors only..

I have my system a central server and the several clients are connected to it on the same network through ip address , at the backend i have defined ip addresses of department to send message to particular ip but all messages are sending to all departments .

This is the code of my queue service

```
public class QueueService
{
    public void QueueMessage(HistoryModel hMsgs)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.Body = hMsgs;
        msg.Recoverable = true;
        //msg.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
        msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter();

        string machine = Environment.MachineName;

        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        string queuePath = "FormatName:Direct=TCP:" + localIP + @"\private$\WebsiteEmails";

        MessageQueue msgQ;

        InsureQueueExists(queuePath);

        msgQ = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
        //msgQ.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
        msgQ.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter();

        msgQ.Send(msg);     // end Sending
    }

    public static void InsureQueueExists(string queuePath)
    {
        //if this queue doesn't exist we will create it
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queuePath))
            MessageQueue.Create(queuePath);
    }
}
```

}

The view code for visitor form

```
<h3>Add History</h3>
                    </legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label class="control-label" for="VisitPurporse">Department<span class="messages">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VisitPurporse)</span></label>
                            <div>
                                <select id="Department_Id" name="Department_Id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="1">Chemistry</option>
                                    <option value="2">Computer Science</option>
                                    <option value="3">Information Technology</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Please help. What will be the scenario if i want to send message to particular department which i selected in dropdown menu

Comment: That code will always send to the same IP Address.

Comment: what is the solution? @simon at rcl

Comment: At the moment, there cannot be one because the question is so incomplete. You say you want to send to different IP addresses according to the Department. I would expect to see some code which chooses an IP address from somewhere by a Department. You are sending to the first InterNetwork address of the local machine; the only possible answer is "Don't do that".

Comment: I dint put any code which chooses an IP address from somewhere by a Department, what is the possible solutions for choosing ip address by a department

Comment: I'm sorry; you have to put some effort in.